# Member detection idiom ambiguity in address

Tags: c++, templates

```
struct Z {
private:
    int y;
};

template<typename T>
struct DetectZ {
    struct Fallback { int x; };
    struct Derived :Fallback, T {};
    template<typename U, int (U::*)> struct SFINAE {};
    template<typename U> static char test(SFINAE<U,&U::x>*);
    template<typename U> static int test(...);
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<Derived>(0)) == sizeof(int);
};

int main() {
    cout << DetectZ<Z>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this return 1. I expect it to return 0 because address using &U::x can be taken without any ambiguity and hence it should return sizeof(char)?

If i change `int (U::*)` to `int (Fallback::*)` then it starts working.

Comment: Because the lookup happens first (ignoring access), and then the access is checked.

Comment: Do you know about C++20 `requires`? It makes all those tricks obsolete.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is `y` and `x`, not `x` in both cases.

Comment: What is this meant to detect? Whether `T` has a data member `y`? Whether `Z` has a data member `x`?

Comment: `int Base::*` versus `int Derived::*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `&Derived::x` is `int Fallback::*`, and not `int Derived::*`. You would expect that `int Fallback::*` would just get implicitly converted to `int Derived::*` for the second template parameter of `struct SFINAE`, but that kind of implicit conversion is not permitted when initializing a template parameter. [[expr.const]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#12) lists the types of implicit conversions that will be done when initializing a template parameter from a template argument.

So `SFINAE<Derived, (int Derived::*)(&Derived::x)>` is allowed (you can do the conversion explicitly, including in a template parameter), and you can also do that conversion implicitly in another context:

```
void foo(int Derived::*);
foo(&Derived::x);  // OK
```

And that conversion is even allowed to be done implicitly in a constant expression:

```
constexpr int Derived::*pm = &Derived::x;  // OK
```

But you can't pass `&Derived::x` to a template parameter of type `int Derived::*`. It just isn't allowed.

This is a longstanding core issue, CWG440, first reported to CWG in 2003. Earlier this year, CWG finally concluded that this is not a defect in the standard and if you want the language to support this, you need to write a proposal.